# Calculus Problem [Calculus I]

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, problem-solving

The sand is falling on a conical pile of sand at a rate of $12\,\text{m}^2 / \text{min},$ so that the diameter of the base of the pile is always $3/2$ of the height. Find the speed at which the height increases when the pile is $2$ meters.

So, I don't even know where to start, I don't know what to do; the problem seems more of a physics problem but it is from a Final Calculus Exam. A hint would be nice.

I don't know if it is important or not but this is the second part of the exercise, while the first part was to find the volume of a cone using an integral.

Comment: The sand pile is a cone. $V = \frac 13 \pi r^2 h$ and it is given that $r = \frac 32 h \implies V = \frac 13 \pi (\frac 94) h^3$  Take the derivative with respect to time.  $\frac {dV}{dt}$ is given.  Find $\frac {dh}{dt}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Your post says that sand is falling on a conical pile at $12\text{m}^2/\text{min}$, which doesn't make much sense–how can an area fall onto a pile? Perhaps the problem asked for $12\text{m}^3/\text{min}$. If that's not the case and the *area* of the base is increasing by $12\text{m}^2/\text{min}$, try and relate area and height as I do in this answer.

This is a related rates problem. First, write down everything you know:

$$d = \frac 32 h \quad V = \frac 13 \pi r^2h \quad \frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dt} = 12\text{m}^3/\text{min}$$

The goal of the exercise is to find $\frac{\mathrm dh}{\mathrm dt}$. We can do this by relating $V$ and $h$. Realize that $12\text{m}^2/\text{min}$ represents the change in volume over time. Since we know the radius is one-half the diameter, and the diameter is $3/2$ the height, we can relate them as such, rewriting purely in terms of $h$:

$$d = \frac 32 h \implies r = \frac 34 h$$
$$V = \frac 13 \pi r^2h \implies V = \frac 13 \pi\left(\frac 34h\right)^2h \implies V = \frac 3{16} \pi h^3$$

Now differentiate and equate:

$${\mathrm dV\over \mathrm dt} = {\mathrm d\over \mathrm dt}\left(\frac 3{16} \pi h^3\right)\implies 12 = \frac 9{16}\pi h^2{\mathrm dh\over \mathrm dt}$$

Now isolate $\frac{\mathrm dh}{\mathrm dt}$ to solve. Since you are trying to find $\frac{\mathrm dh}{\mathrm dt}$ when $h = 2\text{m}$, plug in $2$ for $h$.

Comment: As the question is currently written, $12=\frac{dA}{dt}$ since the units are $m^2/min$, which is a different related rates problem involving the pile's surface area, not volume. This solution is good for $12=\frac{dV}{dt}$ with units $m^3/min$, but the general procedure is the same

Comment: @Andrew-Li First of all thanks. I mean, i get confused because, i mean, m^2/min it seems more of the change of area over time, other than the change of volumen. And the other thing that was a problem for me is that i dont visualize the problem, Any way, it really helped me.

Comment: @Skip Gah, I can't believe I missed that. Will edit!

Comment: @Karl You are entirely correct as Skip noted above. The procedure is the same: relate $A$ and $h$. I will edit right now.

Comment: @AndrewLi All good

Comment: @Skip Edited, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: When the OP said "sand is falling at a rate of $12 \frac {m^2}{\text{min}}$" What does that even mean?  How does sand fall in units of area?!  My best guess is that it is supposed to say $12 \frac {m^3}{\text{min}}$

Comment: @Karl It's easy to get overwhelmed by these kinds of problems at first. The way I picture them is to imagine first a nonchanging situation, write down the equations that govern it, and then remove the staticity by replacing terms in the equations with the required functions, then take the derivative and solve

Comment: @DougM That's what I thought too... I don't know what the OP wants, but I think understanding the procedure is key. I'm not sure if I should keep the original answer or the edited one now.

Comment: It is copied textual from the exam, Maybe there is an error and it should be m^3/min. Since $ V = \frac 13 \pi r^2h$ Can't it be rewritten as  $V = \frac 13 Ah$ and work from that ? And keep the 12m^2/min rate i mean. Don't know

Comment: @Karl But if it's referring to area (not volume), then you wouldn't need volume ($V$) at all. Just use $A$ and $dA/dt$.

Comment: You can see my solution if you look at my answer's revision history (by clicking Edited 10 Minutes Ago)

Comment: What i was trying to say is to find dh/dt starting from dV/dt. Using chain derivatives since i know dA/dt, but i don't know if that makes any sense. I just think they got the statement wrong.

Comment: @Karl If you had $V = \frac 13 Ah$, you would have to apply both the product and chain rules to find that $V' = \frac 13(A'h + Ah')$. I've used prime notation instead of Leibniz here, but everything is wrt $t$.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes thing more complicated since i don't have more data. I see it know. Ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, write down an equation that describes the relationship between variables in your problem. In this case, the variables can be reduced to volume and height of the cone.
$$V=\frac{1}{3}Ah=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h=(\frac{1}{3}\pi\frac{9}{16})h^3$$

Take derivative of the equation above with respect to $t$. Since you know $\frac{dV}{dt}=12$, you can plug that in to find $\frac{dh}{dt}$.